# line between textbox and label wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, textbox, label

I need to create something like this:

[image]

I was thinking to use a label and a textbox, but I don't know how to put that line between them. All that I need is good idea how to do it. Are there other tools to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here... you can try this

```
       <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Margin="5">Name</TextBlock>
                <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0.5"/>
                <TextBlock Margin="5" Grid.Column="2">Michael</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Border` like this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1, 0, 0, 0">
    <TextBox ... />
</Border>
```